# GraphQL client for subscriptions in c++

Tags: c++, websocket, graphql, graphql-subscriptions

I've been looking for some time now, how to implement graphql-subscriptions in `c++` without libgraphqlparser, CAFFQL or cppgraphqlgen which are the recommended libraries for graphql implementations.

Currently i am using `curl` for queries and mutations, which is working so far, but this wont work for subscriptions. In `javascript` Apollo uses a Websocket for this purpose. Is it possible to use a websocket in `c++` to do something similar?

**EDIT**

The GraphhQL server I am currently connecting to is a 1:1 copy of this tutorial: https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/0-introduction/

Here is my implementation:

TestClient.hpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include "jsoncpp/json/reader.h"

class TestClient {
public:
    TestClient();
    virtual ~TestClient();

    void login();
    void subscribe();

protected:
    std::string sendRequest(const std::list<std::string> &header, const std::string &graphQL);
    std::string loadFile(std::string filePath);

private:
    curlpp::Easy *m_request = new curlpp::Easy();
    Json::Reader m_reader;
    std::string m_token = "";
    std::string m_grapqlLogin;
    std::string m_grapqlSubscribe;

    const std::string m_URL                 = "http://localhost:4000/graphiql";
    const std::string m_headerContentType   = "Content-Type: application/json";
    const std::string m_headerToken         = "Authorization:Bearer ";
};
```

TestClient.cpp:

```cpp
#include "TestClient.hpp"

#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Exception.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <exception>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;
using namespace curlpp;

TestClient::TestClient()
{
    m_grapqlLogin = loadFile("./data/login.graphql");
    m_grapqlSubscribe = loadFile("./data/subscribe.graphql");
}


void TestClient::login()
{
    list<string> header = { m_headerContentType };
    Json::Value json;
    string result = sendRequest(header, m_grapqlLogin);

    if(m_reader.parse(result, json, false))
    {
        if(json["errors"] == Json::nullValue)
        {
            cout << json.toStyledString() << endl;
            m_token = json["data"]["login"]["token"].asString();
        }
    }
}

void TestClient::subscribe()
{
    string headerToken = m_headerToken + m_token;
    std::list<string> header = { m_headerContentType, headerToken };
    Json::Value json;
    string result = sendRequest(header, m_grapqlSubscribe);

    if(m_reader.parse(result, json, false))
    {
        if(json["errors"] == Json::nullValue)
        {
            cout << json.toStyledString() << endl;
        }
    }
}

string TestClient::sendRequest(const std::list<string> &header, const string &graphQL)
{
    stringstream result;

    m_request->reset();
    m_request->setOpt<Options::Url>(m_URL);
    m_request->setOpt<Options::Post>(true);
    m_request->setOpt<Options::HttpHeader>(header);
    m_request->setOpt<Options::PostFields>(graphQL);
    m_request->setOpt<Options::PostFieldSize>(graphQL.size());
    m_request->setOpt<Options::WriteStream>(&result);
    m_request->perform();
    
    return result.str();
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
{
   "data" : {
      "login" : {
         "token" : "a long token",
         "user" : {
            "email" : "alice@prisma.io",
            "links" : [
                 {some links}
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "errors" : null
}

{
   "data" : {
      "newLink" : null
   },
   "errors" : null
}
```

Now I don't know how to use curlpp together with subscricptions. Has someone an idea? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, if your graphql server supports subscriptions over websockets then you can use C++ to do subscriptions over websockets. What is your actual question?

Comment: I need to implement subscriptions in c++ without the mentioned libs and i dont know how to do so. So i am searching for an answer how to implement this. And the only answer i could get to this point, that websockets are neccessary. But neither do I know yet how to use them nor do i know if the graphqlserver i am connecting to will implement this, because they are not finished with their implementation. Maybe there is another solution?

Comment: The graphQL specification has very little to say on the topic of how subscriptions are implemented. Typically you either have a stream of responses to a request, or indeed you use a websocket to receive multiple objects. There are tons of websockets libraries for C++, and the protocol tends to be "send a single JSON message and receive a bunch of JSON messages back". I suggest you edit your question with details of the implementation you are developing against or at least the promises "they" have made wrt protocols.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will update my question then.